# batch rename multiple files across multiple folders in centos

Tags: linux, centos, rename, file-rename

This should be simple but can't figure it out:

Original file and folder structure

```
folder1/folderA1/folderA2/folderA3/OLDfile.jpeg
folder1/folderB1/folderB2/folderB3/OLDfile.exr
```

I would like to rename it to:

```
folder1/folderA1/folderA2/folderA3/NEWfile.jpeg
folder1/folderB1/folderB2/folderB3/NEWfile.exr
```

I have tried the rename command which works when directly changing the name inside the folder but cant get it to work with sub-directories across multiple files.

Answer (score -3):

I found this worked for me:

```
find . -depth -iname "*OLD*" -exec rename OLD NEW '{}' \;
```